# Do part-time post doc positions in computer science exist?

Tags: phd, postdocs

I am very close to finishing my Ph.D. in Computer Science and I am working full-time as a software engineer. In fact, I have been working full-time as a software engineer for the past 7 years.

I am currently working in FAANG and I am wondering if there are part-time post-doc positions available similar to what I have been doing in my Ph.D. (part-time at my own pace for the last 5 years). Or is that not an option for post-doc positions? I am in my early 30s and don't want to regret that I missed an opportunity.

Comment: It depends on the country; if the law for working hours allows and you get an offer you can do it; you can also do a postdoc in your company or another one, to get your answer come with more details, university, area, country, experiences,

Comment: What is your career goal, and in that context, what is the purpose of the postdoc position that you have in mind?

Comment: @henning to continue learning more in the field of computer science/compilers even though these may not be directly used in industry.

Comment: " don't want to regret that I missed an opportunity." which opportunity, exactly? People doing their postdoc full time are already struggling with advancing to further academic positions, so I would say that doing a postdoc as a 50%, or 30% is not *helping* any academic opportunity.
If, on the other hand, your "opportunity" are in terms of advancing research ... ask your company. Or ask your family/relative other what do they think if you spend your free time doing research.

Comment: I personally think a full-time job in software engineering is enough to keep one occupied.  Often, they expect more than 40 hours a week.  Of course, if you want to do research as a second job, that's up to you (if your company doesn't have rules against it).  To my way of thinking, it's very unwise, however.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. I did two postdocs after my PhD, one in CS, the other in Biology. The CS postdoc was Part-Time. In my case, the research group needed help with a grant-funded project, but could not afford a full-time postdoc, so they offered me a part-time position. At the time I already had another job as an administrator at another institution in the same city, so it worked perfectly for both sides. I learned a lot, and they were very happy with my work.

I know of many other postocs who have worked part-time. The issue is that these positions are usually not advertised, but you find them through your own network. Someone needs short-term part-time help finishing up a project, e.g. help a group of grad students wrap up a project and write the papers. Another PI needs some technical assistance, e.g. writing code to automate a process, etc.

Remember that "postdoc" only means "job you get after the PhD", and that postdoc positions range from grant-funded mini-professorships with your own space, students, etc., to underpaid technician or teaching positions, with everything in between. So the answer to the question of "can I get a part-time postdoc" is *yes*. The answer to "can I get a worthwhile part-time postdoc" is *maybe*.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your field of study, there are research groups that would not mind incorporating a recent Ph.D. in their on-going work, but they would probably prefer to spend their grant monies on their own graduate students instead of someone they would only see occasionally. Your paid part-time post-doc while working a challenging job is not something that academia is set up for. My expectations would be that the post-doc quickly drops out of active research since the immediate goal of the Ph.D. is already achieved.

On a personal level, you need to decide what your goals are. If you want to be active in research, you need to either go into academia full-time or you need to find a paid job that allows you to do research. After all, your Ph.D. should have trained you to work in Research and Development.